# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, moderator-elections

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that uses the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).

The information presented is:

The nominees election

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

*This might take a couple of days to become live, but I'm posting this now before I forget.*